# Getting Bad request error while loading a model in forge viewer from AWS S3

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I am using AWS S3 to store my f2d, manifest and metadata files. My AWS S3 bucket is public so that I can access these file using their URL. Now I tried to load a model using **myViewer.loadModel(AWS_Url, opts);** , and got Bad Request error. Does anyone have any idea what I might have gone wrong?

[This is the error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68FF7.png)

Thank You,

Comment: Not exactly sure the reason of the issue, can not tell much from the response. Please check my colleague's code pen at https://codepen.io/gonzomustang/pen/WXwNdz , he is load the model from github.io, it works fine as expected.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more information and make this as official reply. Yes, the viewer can open files directly from S3, without your viewer code, there is not much information that can be got from the response, maybe you can try this way:

```
myViewer.start(AWS_Url, opts)
```

Please also check the sample that load f2d from S3 at    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3d.html?v=3.2.*&svf=https://lmv-models.s3.amazonaws.com/2d_model/primaryGraphics.f2d

Comment: Yes I was looking for something like code pen you have shared above. Thank you.

Comment: @zhong-wu, Is there any autodesk viewer API available to view .DWG format file through AWS S3 URL?